# String changed when parsed in the notification using bundle of the contentIntent

Tags: android, notifications, bundle

I am using bundle to parse a string in the `notification.` I can see the String is definitely what I set before parsed. However, when I catch it in the activity started by the `contentIntent` of the notification, the String is different!

And, almost all of the characters in the string is definitely same as what I set except one subString changed to an integer.

**E.g.** The string I set was like `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage/files/filename.mp4"`,
But what I caught in the activity started by the notification was something like `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage/files/15678.mp4"`

Now, I find it runs correctly on my motorola droid bionic, but the problem still exists on Samsung galaxy S3.

Could anyone help me? And what is the mechanism which lead to this exception?

**Some code is listed here:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
    Bundle pathBundle = new Bundle();
    Log.e("PATH", path);
    pathBundle.putString(Utils.PATH_BUNDLE, path);
    intent.putExtras(pathBundle);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    notificationManager.notify(msg.arg1, notification);
```

**and the code to get the string path:**

```
Bundle pathBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    filePath = pathBundle.getString(Utils.PATH_BUNDLE);
    Log.v("FILEpath", filePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem is caused by:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);
```

The document of getActivity is here `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)`

The flag 0x00000000 is caused the null result on Galaxy S3.

And, for multiple pendingIntent, if necessary, requestCode should be different.